# Improving a basic neural network with only 3 input columns

Tags: deep-learning, keras, regression, python-3.x

I am just getting started with neural networks, and I was hoping someone could shed some light on an issue I keep facing with a model I am working on. I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
df:

x1     x2    x3      y1
70     3     0.25    0.4
80     4     0.5     1.0
70     4     1.25    0.5
...    ...    ...     ...
```

...with a shape of (400, 4)

My objective is to train a deep learning model to predict the y1 value using the x1, x2, and x3 inputs.

Here is my code so far adapted from [this source](https://machinelearningmastery.com/regression-tutorial-keras-deep-learning-library-python/):

```
import pandas
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

# define base model
def baseline_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(3, input_dim=3, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_percentage_error', optimizer='sgd')
    return model

kfold = KFold(n_splits=10)

estimator = KerasRegressor(build_fn=baseline_model, epochs=100, batch_size=5, verbose=0)
results = cross_val_score(estimator, X_train, y_train, cv=kfold)
print("Results: %.2f (%.2f) MSE" % (results.mean(), results.std()))
```

However, my results are a little unusual:

Results: -122.97 (87.82) MSE

```
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
y_pred
```

array([[0.9994005],
[0.9994005],
[0.9994005],
[0.9994005], ...)

My main questions here are why are the final values always the same, in this case "0.9994005", and what can I do to improve this model? What the main things you look for in deep learning models that direct you in the right path?

Comment: What would you get with a more common loss (mse) and a better optimizer (adam)? Moreover you might want to standardize X to allow faster convergence.

Comment: Normalise or scale input? Also I would increase batch size to at least 32 or 64.

Answer (score 1):

*There is no point in looking at the prediction at this point. Your model has not learnt the data yet.*

**Suggestions** -

- When copy from a source. Try copying everything first. Run it and then start tweaking for learning Or to map with your own need. You have changed a few things as compared to what Jason has in his post
- **Use the wisdom of researchers**. So, you can keep a few things as default -

       1. **Optimizer** - Adam

       2. **Activation** - Relu for Hidden layer

       3. **Loss** - MSE(Regression), Cross-entropy(Classification). Beware of Cros-entropy variance.

       4. **Activation for Output layer** - Linear(Regression), Sigmoid/Softmax(Classification)

       3. Have Batch normalization layer when you have a deep network.
- **Try to know why** behind every point that I have mentioned. It's will be an easy search on the Internet.
- A good place to start can be - *Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras, and TensorFlow, 2nd Edition, by Aurélien Géron*

  Further reading -

       [Practical Recommendations for Gradient-Based Training of Deep Architectures, by Yoshua Bengio](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.5533v2.pdf)

      [Andrej Karpathy blog](https://karpathy.github.io/2019/04/25/recipe/)

      [Raúl Gómez blog](https://gombru.github.io/2018/05/23/cross_entropy_loss/)

Answer (score 0):

I could be because of your loss function. I would suggest using "mean_squared_error" as the loss function. Also, try to normalize your data before feeding it into the neural networks.